# Rotation Number of the Henon Map

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I would like to plot the rotation number of the last KAM of the Henon Map over several inital conditions. This means that for the 2D map:

$\qquad x_{i+1}=x_i \cos \alpha - \sin \alpha (y_i-x_i^2 ),\\  \qquad y_{i+1}=x_i \sin \alpha + \cos \alpha (y_i-x_i^2)$

I would like to calculate the number: $\sigma = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i}^N \sigma _i}{N}$
So I have written the following:

```
x = Array[0 &, {10000}];
y = Array[0 &, {10000}];
σ = Array[0 &, {10000}];
S = 0
x[[1]] = 0.1;
y[[1]] = x[[1]];
α = 0.4*Pi;
Do[x[[i + 1]] = x[[i]]*Cos[α] - Sin[α]*(y[[i]] - x[[i]]^2); 
y[[i + 1]] = 
x[[i]]*Sin[α] + Cos[α]*(y[[i]] - x[[i]]^2);σ[[i]] = 
ArcCos[y[[i + 1]]/(Sqrt[x[[i + 1]]^2 + y[[i + 1]]^2])] - 
ArcCos[y[[i]]/(Sqrt[x[[i]]^2 + y[[i]]^2])], {i, 9999}]
ListPlot[Table[{x[[i]], y[[i]]}, {i, 1, 10000}]]
ListPlot[Table[σ[[i]], {i, 1, 9999}]]
Do[S = (S + σ[[i]])/10^4, {i, 9999}]
```

which works just fine for one initial condition $x_1=y_1$. How can I now add more initial conditions in the loop and calculate the $\sigma$ for each one of these so that I make a plot $\sigma$ versus, lets say $x_i$ (or $y_i$ does not matter since in my case they are equal)?

It is important that all the pairs of initial conditions are between 0.1 and 0.7

Comment: Why not use `S = Mean[σ]` in place of `Do[S = (S + σ[[i]])/10^4, {i, 9999}]`? Unless I misunderstand your purpose, your calculation of `S` is not even correct. (you shouldn't be dividing by 10^4 at every iteration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the best way to fix your code. I don't have time to rewrite it in functional style. But this will let you generate your curves and limit approximations.

The key to running your process with different initial values (and also allowing for specifying the number of iterations) is to define a function taking those parameters as arguments.

```
henon[init_, n_] :=
  With[{α = 0.4*Pi},
    Module[{x, y, σ},
      x = ConstantArray[0, n];
      y = ConstantArray[0, n];
      σ = ConstantArray[0, n];
      x[[1]] = y[[1]] = init; 
      σ[[1]] = Null;
      Do[
        x[[i + 1]] = x[[i]]*Cos[α] - Sin[α]*(y[[i]] - x[[i]]^2);
        y[[i + 1]] = x[[i]]*Sin[α] + Cos[α]*(y[[i]] - x[[i]]^2); 
        σ[[i + 1]] =
          ArcCos[y[[i + 1]]/(Sqrt[x[[i + 1]]^2 + y[[i + 1]]^2])] -
          ArcCos[y[[i]]/(Sqrt[x[[i]]^2 + y[[i]]^2])],
        {i, n - 1}];
      {x, y, σ}]]
```

With this definition, your example can be reproduced as follows.

The xy plot.

```
h[.1] = henon[.1, 1000];

ListPlot[Transpose[h[.1][[1 ;; 2]]]]
```

[image: xyplot]

The σ plot

```
ListPlot[h[.1][[3]]]
```

[image: sigmaplot]

```
S = Mean[Rest[h[.1][[3]]]]
```

> `-0.000639365`

To run the process for many initial values is easy.

```
With[{n = 1000}, Do[h[i] = henon[i, n], {i, .1, .6, .1}]]
```

The approximations to the `σ` limits is given by

```
Table[Mean[Rest[h[i][[3]]]], {i, .1, .6, .1}]
```

> ```
> {-0.000639365, -0.000273044, 0.0000968227, 0.000195651, 
>  -0.000465987, -0.000645517}
> ```

Note: I do not show `h[.7]` because that evaluation produces numeric errors. I do not have time to explore the problem which is probably more mathematical than Mathematica-ish.

#### Update

This is to answer an issue raised by the OP in a comment made below.

The last Do-loop above produces six indexed variables `h[.1], ..., h[.6]`, each storing a 3 x n array containing all the data needed to plot `x`, `y`, and `σ` in any combination.

To plot `σ` against `x` for the initial condition `x = .3`, you simply need to write

```
ListPlot[Transpose[h[.3][[{1, 3}]]]]
```

because data for initial condition `x = .3` is assigned to h[.3]; the x-values are in row 1 and the σ-values are in row 3. In this case, you would get

[image: xsigmaplot]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this piece of code. I will try it and let you know how it works. Btw, the overflow at $.7$ is expected, since this is a chaotic map. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, everything seems fine, but still how can I plot the $\sigma$ versus each $x_i$ initial condition?

Comment: @Mitscaype. The vector `h[i][[3]]]` contains the `σ` data for initial condition $x_i$. Look at how I made the  `σ` plot for $x_1$.

Comment: Yeap I can see this. But I need to plot the sigma versus not only $x_1$ but all $x_i$. For every initial condition I will get a different sigma, like you did for $x_1=0.1$. So what I really want is a plot of those sigmas on the vertical axes versus each $x_i$ on the horizontal axes. But I do not know how to extract those $x_i$ from your code :/

Comment: @Mitscaype. See the update I added to my answer.

Comment: Hello and sorry for my late answer. Perhaps it was me that I did not ask the question properly, but I would like to plot the value of each sigma correspoding to each initial condition, versus this initial condition. Neverthelss, your way of formulating the function and so on help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @Mitscaype. I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by "each sigma correspoding to each initial condition". For each initial condition, there are 1000 σ values. Perhaps you want to plot $S(x_i)$ against $x_i$?

Comment: Well, for each IC there are 1000 $\sigma$ values, but then I just take the average of those. So for lets say 500 ICs I keep 500 average sigmas and then I plot them versus the correspoding ICs of each average. :) But I managed to do so, your thinking of functions helped me a lot. Perhaps I can post it here later, to demonstrate what I mean. Thank you again.

Comment: @Mitscaype. That is what I mean by $S(x_i)$. You can plot that with `ListPlot[Table[{i, Mean[Rest[h[i][[3]]]]}, {i, .1, .6, .1}]]`

Comment: Indeed, I now see that your write about plotting $S(x_i)$ versus $x_i$ in your previous comment. But I managed to do it, so everything is ok.